# mingw32-gcc.exe: error: F: No such file or directory

Tags: c, codeblocks

I can't even compile hello world in codeblocks. Code is right, I've tried it in linux and worked great. But I cant find what is wrong pls help.

Error

> mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 F  -c
>   C:\Users\K\Desktop\FOLDER\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o
>   mingw32-gcc.exe: error: F: No such file or directory
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
>   1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf(
    "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the command line you posted, and then read the error message. It very clearly tells you what the problem is, and even exactly where it's located. It's extremely important to learn to **actually read the words** in error messages; they almost always contain useful information. **Read the message**.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that the file `F` does not exist.  That appears in the command line `mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 F -c` after the optimization level switch.

I bet if you replace `F` with the file name (hello.c?), it will work as expected.

Comment: how could i change it?

Comment: @Theredone:  I don't know how codeblocks works, but if it is a GUI IDE, then you probably have to look in the project parameters.  To test the compile and link part, type the `mingw32-gcc.exe ...` at a command prompt.